# Linq to Sql distinct with left join, Lambda

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I'm trying to rewrite the query below into a Linq statement. 
The query should return a List of "User" objects containing the four properties (Id, FirstName, LastName, Email).

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM User
LEFT JOIN Booklet ON Booklet.UserId = User.Id
WHERE Booklet.YearReleased = @YearOfRelease 
ORDER BY LastName ASC
```

Now I have something like this, but the Group by is incorrect and it all doesn't look very good coding...i feel like this can be optimized a lot into a single statement but I fail to do so. (demo year '18').

```
List<User> = new List<User>();

List<int?> lstUserIds = db.Booklet.GroupBy(x => x.UserId && x.YearReleased)
                                  .Where(x => x.YearReleased == 18)
                                  .OrderBy(x => x.LastName)
                                  .Select(x => x.UserId)
                                  .ToList();

foreach (int iUserId in lstUserIds )
    lst.Add(db.User.First(x => x.Id == iUserId));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Any()` you don't need distinct nor left join to booklet.

```
var users = db.User
             .Where(u => db.Booklet.Any(b => u.Id == b.UserId && b.YearReleased == 18))
             .OrderBy(u => u.LastName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tr this:

```
List<User> lst = db.User.Include(B => B.Booklet)
                        .Where(B => B.YearReleased == 18)
                        .OrderBy(x => x.LastName)
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a join to get Left Outer Join :

```
List<int?> lstUserIds = (from b in db.Booklet.Where(x => x.YearReleased == 18)
    join on u in User on b.Id equal u.Id into ids
    from id in ids.DEfaultIfEmpty
    select new { user = u, books = b})
    .OrderBy(x => x.user.LastName)
    .GroupBy(x -> x.user.UserId)
    .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```